# Object / Hashmap Lookup Slow

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I'm using objects as a transition table for a Trie structure I am trying to implement, but am finding that lookups for objects, particularly misses, are slowing my program down by a large margin.

The object maps strings to nodes, e.g:

```
"c" => TrieNode()
```

From the profiler the biggest time user is this:

```
[C++ entry points]:
    ticks   cpp    total   name
    9178   99.1%   63.8%   v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedLoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
```

Comment: Have you tried using [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of objects?

Comment: Maps significantly sped things up, but now calling `get` on the map is the biggest drain on execution speed at 2k ticks. This is not the speed I expected for O(1) access time

Comment: Using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringmap) I am able to get even better performance, but inspecting the code it appears to just use objects.

Also I believe misses are causing significant slowdowns

Comment: That's a tricky situation. Have you tried comparing your results to any microbenchmarks? The only things I can think to do now are: make sure you're not doing anything that would cause your code to not be optimized by the compiler (I have no clue where to even start with this). Or maybe look into moving this part of your code-base into a native module and access it using something like node-gyp.

Good luck!

Comment: Looking at the profiler seems to show every function is optimized. Rewriting in a lower level language will probably be what gets to the next level of performance, but I want to squeeze out as much from js before going there. I think I'll need to implement my own hashmap class in javascript